# Remove or delete selected feature in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

Using OpenLayers 3.9.0.
I have two vector layers which are both desplayed on the map and can select any feature with a singleclick `var select = new ol.interaction.Select();`

Now I need to make it possible to remove selected feature with Del key.

I ended up with creating the folloing function and listener

```
var deleteFeature = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 46 && (select !== null)){
        layer.getSource().removeFeature(select.getFeatures());
    }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', deleteFeature, false);
```

but the problem is that I don't know the layer of the selected feature to call the removeFeture method on.

Any suggestions how to find out the layer of the selected feature or another way of removing selected features?

Comment: [I found a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391195/how-to-add-event-handler-to-feature-in-open-layers-3) which works based on `forEachFeatureAtPixel`, maybe you can combine that somehow with `interaction.getFeatures()`. It certainly is not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** to achieve when layer is within a `ol.layer.Group`.
Now you should pass **`map`** reference to method.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/r242y7ke/

A method to get `ol.layer.Vector` from feature you can use like so:

```
/**
 * This is a workaround.
 * Returns the associated layer.
 * @param {ol.Map} map.
 * @return {ol.layer.Vector} Layer.
 */
ol.Feature.prototype.getLayer = function(map) {
    var this_ = this, layer_, layersToLookFor = [];
    /**
     * Populates array layersToLookFor with only
     * layers that have features
     */
    var check = function(layer){
        var source = layer.getSource();
        if(source instanceof ol.source.Vector){
            var features = source.getFeatures();
            if(features.length > 0){
                layersToLookFor.push({
                    layer: layer,
                    features: features
                });
            }
        }
    };
    //loop through map layers
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer){
        if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
            layer.getLayers().forEach(check);
        } else {
            check(layer);
        }
    });
    layersToLookFor.forEach(function(obj){
        var found = obj.features.some(function(feature){
            return this_ === feature;
        });
        if(found){
            //this is the layer we want
            layer_ = obj.layer;
        }
    });
    return layer_;
};
```

Then loop through `select.getFeatures()` and get `ol.layer.Vector`:

```
select.getFeatures().forEach(function(feature){
    var layer = feature.getLayer(map);
    //and so on
});
```

Used here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31299728/4640499

Comment: Won't looping throu all layers and features cause a performance issue if there are many layers and many features? Isn't there some built in solution for this?

Comment: No, no built in solution. And it is a cheap looping.

Comment: Thanks @JonatasWalker. Your getlayer function works well.

Comment: For those how are going to use this solution, be aware that after you remove a feature from a source you have to call `select.getFeatures().remove(feature);` function to remove the feature from the map.

Comment: The method fails if the layer is in a layer group.

Comment: Updated answer.